# how to protect signup in devise using a security key in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In devise I want to authenticate signup for admin. only that person can signup who has a predefined random string. I want to do this for all devises except user. i have admin, faculty, student, branch and parent login. so i want to allow those to signup who has a key which provided by me and different for all login system. I want to do this by scaffold to create a new security key for those logins and edit any time.
So Please help me how to do this task .

Comment: This is like you will send a invite to user with key and the user who has the key can only sign up. You can try this https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable

Comment: Not helpful because after reading this and read usages it shows that its not a proper solution because if i will follow this then any one can signup via getting token key from their email but i want to allows those who have security key

Comment: You can append you security key to the link which you will be sending to user and when user comes to your application, you can check for that security key right?

Comment: please describe in deep because there is a very short time to respond towards solution so i can not much more read and experiment on this If is there any solution like you described me please share 
in advance much more thanks....

Comment: can i go for the simple solution could be done in minimum of time that to add some other text field in signup form and in model i use validation.

Comment: If you add some other text field in signup form. but with this how you will give user the `secret key`. WHich user has to enter in that textfield

Comment: really i don't know how it would be possible but in jquery there are some validation like you have to enter the same pair of string which has defined as for validation. So i can get help of this. if any  of help i can get from you i sure try and do .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, this is not exact code.

Suppose you have `User` model
define class method which will generate random secret key

```
def self.generate_uniq_id
   chars = 'ABCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ'
   nums = '0123456789'
   result = ''
   5.times { |i| result << chars[rand(chars.length)] }
   4.times { |i| result << nums[rand(nums.length)] }
   result
end
```

Then invite user by email and in email send generated link by`signup_users_path(User.generate_uniq_id)`with the `secret_key`. And when user will click on that link user will be redirected to your website.
`signup_users_path(User.generate_uniq_id)`
define action in `routes.rb` as `signup` which will handle when user is landed on the website 
Validate the secret_key from the link, and allow user to register or redirect back to `home` page

Comment: dude you have to send the link to person you want to invite. When user click on sign up button on your portal do whatever you want to do. This will be different way to signup. That link will take to some other action that method will check if that secret_key is valid or not, if valid do your signup process as you are doing for others